# AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen

Tags: java, android, xml

I got below error when trying to build APK using Android Studio:

> AAPT: error: resource **style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen** (aka com.snowyapps.belajarabc:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen) not found.
>   error: resource style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen (aka com.snowyapps.belajarabc:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen) not found.
>   error: failed linking references.

any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change to `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`
Or you may create a custom theme if using Holo light is a must

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

and then simply use `style/MyTheme`

Comment: you don't have cardBackgroundColor defined in strings.xml. It's really hard to tell without looking at the code. Please use the latest Android Studio version, it will automatically highlight any xml problems for you ;)

Comment: @anunixercoder please accept this if it answers your original question. Try to change the facebook version SDK to 4.8.0 then it won't use that resource file.